# Remove media previously included in presentation

Tags: iwork-keynote

In Keynote (8.1), how to really remove media that was previously included in a presentation?

By default, files (images, videos, etc) are embedded in the Keynote presentation. But even after removing a video from the slides, the presentation's file size doesn't decrease. When unzipping the `.key` file, I can see that the video/image is still present in the `Data` directory.

I've tried the File > Reduce file size  feature, but this is about compressing / cropping existing files. It doesn't remove un-referenced media.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this is not simple. The best thing of course is to disable "Copy audio and movies into document" before you add them. But it seems even with this disabled, the previously added media will always be saved even if you delete and re-add it.

What worked for me (Keynote 13.2)

- Make sure "Copy audio and movies into document" is unchecked
- Delete all the videos
- Save As to a new file
- (Probably unnecessary) Quit Keynote and reopen it
- Add the videos back in